# Show image when certain amount of people has registered to the course

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements, elementor

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTF9U.png) 
I am using Elementor to create a website for online courses and I am trying to find a solution for making a condition. I have this section which shows online courses and the "Anmelden" button is for registering to the course. I want to show this traffic light image when a certain number of participants has registered to the course.

Does anyone have an idea how can i do that?

Comment: How are the courses stored in WordPress (Custom Post Types with attached meta data?) and is the number of registered / maximum members stored anywhere? If course applications are also handled by your site (by logged-in users, for example),  this can be done creating a custom shortcode, querying for registered and max. amount of participants for each course, and showing a traffic light image based on that. We need more information about how this course list is populated and what data it might already provide. How does creating / registering for a course work?